# Displaying point on MapView without coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there a way of showing a point on the google MapView without knowing its coordinates, with just an address?

My goal is to avoid using the geocoding API, which I understand has a usage limit. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Android [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class you can do that.. You can get Latitude , Longitude by the given address..

Something like,

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> address;

try {
    address = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("Address",1);
    if (address == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Address location = address.get(0);
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();
}
```

And

```
My goal is to avoid using the geocoding API, which I understand has a usage limit. Is this correct?
```

As you said you don't want to limit on query ...

So look at these two links [android-geocoder-limitations](http://java.dzone.com/android-geocoder-limitations)  and SE Question [/how-to-avoid-google-map-geocode-limit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/how-to-avoid-google-map-geocode-limit) It will help you…